# "MulterError: Unexpected field" when using together Unity and Node.js server

Tags: c#, node.js, unity-game-engine, multer

I tried to upload a single file generated by `Unity` to a Web server generated by `Node.js`, but I get an error.

The code of the web server is as follows. It simply handles file upload requests.

```
const express = require('express');
const mysql   = require('mysql');
const multer  = require('multer');
const fs      = require('fs');
const app     = express();

app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/uploads'));
app.listen(3005, () => {
  console.log('server started');
});

let storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function(req, file, callback) {
    callback(null, 'uploads/');
  },
  filename: function(req, file, callback) {
    callback(null, file.originalname);  
  }
});

let upload = multer({
  storage : storage
});

app.post('/fileUpload', upload.single('file'), (req, res, next) => {
  let file = req.file;
});
```

Here's the `Unity` side code.

```
using System.IO;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Networking;

public class FileUpload : MonoBehaviour
{
    public string filePath;

    public void UploadProcess()
    {
        StartCoroutine(Upload());
    }

    IEnumerator Upload()
    {
        List<IMultipartFormSection> formData = new List<IMultipartFormSection>();
        formData.Add(new MultipartFormFileSection("file", filePath));

        UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequest.Post("http://localhost:3005/fileUpload", formData);
        yield return www.SendWebRequest();

        if(www.isNetworkError || www.isHttpError)
        {
            Debug.Log(www.error);
        }
        else 
        {
            Debug.Log("Form upload complete!");
        }
    }
}
```

When I run the code, `Unity` outputs the following error:

> HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error

Also web server outputs the following error:

> MulterError : Unexpected field at wrappedFileFilter ...

I don't know exactly what is wrong.

Comment: What is the value of the `filePath` variable? Is it something Unity can access?

Comment: @nIcEcOw Yes, `filePath` is `string` type variable. For example, "Assets/uploadTest.txt".

Comment: It seems more of a `multer`'s error instead of being Unity's error!!!! It turns out I am getting the same error, or it might can so happen `multer` is not accepting multipart format as send by Unity.

Comment: Seems like if I use `formidable` instead of `multer` than the problem seems to resolve and file is getting saved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be some issue with the `multer` package. If I use `formidable` instead of `multer` seems like the problem is resolved.

Unity Coroutine to upload file:

```
private IEnumerator UploadFile () {
    List < IMultipartFormSection > formData = new List < IMultipartFormSection > ();
    byte [] arr = File.ReadAllBytes ( Path.Combine ( Application.dataPath, "image.jpg" ) );
    formData.Add ( new MultipartFormFileSection ( "background.jpg", arr ) );
    
    UnityWebRequest request = UnityWebRequest.Post ( "http://127.0.0.1:9000/upload", formData );
    yield return request.SendWebRequest ();
    
    if ( request.result != UnityWebRequest.Result.Success ) {
        Debug.LogError ( $"<color=red>Upload error: {request.error}</color>" );
    } else {
        Debug.Log ( "<color=cyan>Upload successful</color>" );
    }
}
```

And this is the nodejs code for "**formidable**" part, rest is same as yours:

```
const formidable = require ( 'formidable' );
const incomingForm = formidable.IncomingForm;


app.post ( '/upload', function ( req, res ) ) {
    let form = new incomingForm ();
    form.uploadDir = "upload"; // This is the directory you have to create manually.
    form.parse ( req, function ( err, fields, files ) {
        if ( err ) {
            console.log ( 'Some error: ', err );
        }
        console.log ( 'File saved' );
    } );
}
```

Comment: Awesome! That's worked. Is `formidable` a famous package? And what's the biggest difference with `multer`?

Comment: @MinwooKim: Seems like this question belongs to someone proficient in NodeJS. I just use it every now and then to sort out small things, but just a beginner in NodeJS. I just knew one or two packages, but still learning NodeJS. Seems like you have to ask this question under the NodeJS tag, for someone with the knowledge to answer on this topic.